# How to improve: "not a friend, not a foe, just so"?

Tags: phrase-request

I was recently trying to explain to my U.K. friend lyrics of a famous song by a Soviet poet, V. Vysotsky, "Song About a Friend". I found an excellent translation [here](https://sites.google.com/site/poetryandtranslations/vladimir-vysotsky/song-about-a-friend). However, I find a major inconsistency there which makes the whole idea diminished. Here's an excerpt:

> If your friend just became a man,
>   Not a friend, not a foe, - **just so**,
>   If you cannot decide from the start,
>   If he’s strong in his heart...

*Just so* seems to be a literal translation.
The Free Dictionary [suggests](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/just+so) that *just so* means "precisely right".
The original meaning of "а так" is something like "but something in between" or "but nothing in particular".

**What is the correct way to express it in English?**

P.S. I don't care if it versifies well or not.

Comment: Just a lustful hoe. HA-HA! Kidding, just kidding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a minimally-obtrusive change, add *so-* before *so*:

> Not a friend, not a foe, – just so-so,

Note, as an adjective *[so-so](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so-so#Adjective)* means  “Neither good nor bad; tolerable, passable, indifferent”.

Also consider  *[neutral](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/neutral)* (in its sense “not siding with any party...”) and   *[medium](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/medium#Adjective)* (in its sense “Of intermediate size, degree, amount”).

Comment: I guess _medium_ and _neutral_ are too... er... neutral. :) "So-so" is maybe the best term as it conveys a minor amount of disregard which is required here.

Answer (score 2):

There's an English idiom "neither fish nor fowl". It means "[Something or someone that is neither fish nor fowl doesn't really fit into any one group.](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/neither+fish+nor+fowl.html#badWQyx5cwF7iIH2.99)"

> If your friend just became a man,
>   Not a friend, not a foe, - neither fish nor fowl,
>   If you cannot decide from the start,
>   If he’s strong in his heart...

Answer (score 1):

While I've upvoted the answer submitted by user264, I would also add to the answer submitted by jwpat7 to say, "Not a friend, not a foe, -- just *a so-and-so*."

The reason I suggest this is because "friend" and "foe" are both nouns, so to maintain parallelism, I would use a noun as well, i.e., "[so-and-so](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=so%20and%20so%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=d9TkWI6BJ9T48AfD5YSgBQ)."

Incidentally, because "so-and-so" is also a noun about a person (or thing whose name the speaker does not need to specify or does not know or remember, ("so-and-so," Google.com)), this word fits on multiple levels.

Comment: Two senses, "unnamed or unspecified something" vs “unpleasant person” usually are given in definitions of *so-and-so* [1](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/so-and-so),[2](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/so-and-so),[3](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so-and-so),[4](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/so-and-so).  But the friend is known or named and sense 1 doesn't apply.  In other words, using the phrase “just a so-and-so” would call the friend a difficult or unpleasant person; which is probably not the intent here.